# MySQL Query from SSH

Tags: mysql, command-line

Im trying to use SSH to connect my Server and use a MySQL Query. (As a logging report)

```
ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa me@serverIP mysql --defaults-file="/srv/home/my_username/.my.cnf" --database=database_1 "'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tl_lead` WHERE from_unixtime(created,'%Y-%m-%d') <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and form_id = 8' mysql";
```

I want only the number of the count back.

But I get the error from MySQL> ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name

.my.cnf file

```
[client]
user=my_secret_username
password=naLOJ36Q4JWShMgp9nxNMt

[mysql]
database=database_1
```

In PHPMYAdmin, this Query s working.
SSH connection is working.

How can I change this line to get it work?

Answer (score 0):

Your sql command had also a quoting problem.  No idea what the "mysql" at the end signified.

```
ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa me@serverIP mysql \
    --defaults-file="/srv/home/my_username/.my.cnf" \
    --database=database_1 \
    -e "\"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tl_lead` WHERE from_unixtime(created,'%Y-%m-%d') <= (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) and form_id = 8\""
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, now I get a different Error `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
`

Comment: I've added a couple of escaped quotes, can you try if they pass unscathed?